# Padrões de telas Web design reponsive

Tags: webdesign

Gostaria de saber quais são os padrões de telas (Smartphon, tablet, laptop e desktop) para eu fazer o meu site responsivo ?

Sei que existem muitos tipos mais queria especificamente um padrão que normalmente os design usam (Largura e altura),

Answer (score 0):

Olá, amigo! 
Já passei por essa mesma questão, segue os breakpoints que utilizo:

Smartphones <768px 
Tablets ≥768px 
Notebooks ≥992px 
Desktops ≥1200px 

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços!

Comment: te amo mais preciso da altura também .-. (Largura e altura)